# HAVE you talked this through+before you MADE this...(tense confusion)

Tags: tense

Let's say your bestfriend and his girlfriend has finally decided to **marry** each other. Knowing that, you now ask them if they **talked** the marriage **through**, and you say:

> **Have** you guys **talked this through** before you **made** that decision.

Or

> **Have** you guys **talked this through** before you **made** that decision.

From my research, as for the sequence of events, the **present perfect tense** comes first and then the **past tense** if the situation is still happening right? But should I add **HAD**(from sentence#2) or not?

Comment: I think you're confusing the usage of have here.  If I say, "Have you camped before?" I'm not asking if you're currently camping.  Similarly, "Have you guys talked this through" doesn't imply they're actively talking about it.

Comment: I know what you mean in your example, but I added ''before you made this decision'' right. That's what I am not sure.

Comment: Well the second is wrong, but as these things sometimes go, I couldn't tell you exactly *why* it's wrong.  I don't think you typically use pluperfect unless it's an event in the past being compared to a more recent event in the past.

Comment: I have never seen have had + pp! Your second sentence sounds awkward!

Comment: A better way to say this sentence: *Have you guys talked this through before making that decision?*

Comment: Now it's clearer to me now with all your comments here. Got it. and thx for the suggestion helen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Have you guys had talked this through* would be ungrammatical - a kind of past-past-perfect.

*Have you talked this through* is asking about something in the past but with present relevance: the relevance being that they are in a state of having agreed what they would do.

*Did you talk this through* would also be possible. As usual, the choice of present perfect or past is nothing to do with the objective events, but rather in how the speaker is choosing to structure them temporally.

I agree that it is a little odd to use the present perfect for the discussion, and then the simple past for the action which followed it; but only a little odd. The present perfect could not be used for "made", because it can't follow "before" in the past (it can do with future meaning), so it had to be "made" in the past. The simple past was possible for "talked this through", as I said, but so is the present perfect.